# Exception creating MSMQ queue in DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, msmq

I'm trying to code some MSMQ functionality into a dll (c++) but am having trouble. Essentially when I make a call to create a queue a low-level exception is raised (see callstack below). What's frustrating me is that this code works fine in an executable, it only seems to fail when it's sitting in a dll. I've sanitized the code a bit and included below.

Callstack:

```
KernelBase.dll!_RaiseException@16()  + 0x58 bytes   
msvcrt.dll!__CxxThrowException@8()  + 0x45 bytes    
mqsec.dll!CCancelRpc::Init()  + 0xa5 bytes  
mqrt.dll!CFreeRPCHandles::Add()  + 0x1bc bytes  
mqrt.dll!RtpOneTimeThreadInit()  + 0x39 bytes   
mqrt.dll!_MQCreateQueue@16()  + 0x23 bytes  
mqoa.dll!CMSMQQueueInfo::Create()  + 0xba bytes
```

Code:

```
 HRESULT CreateQueue()
 {
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    CComQIPtr<IMSMQQueueInfo, &IID_IMSMQQueueInfo> ipQueueInfo;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MSMQQueueInfo,
     NULL,
     CLSCTX_SERVER,
     IID_IMSMQQueueInfo,
     (void**)(&ipQueueInfo.p));

    if(hr != S_OK)
      return hr;

    hr = ipQueueInfo->put_PathName(L".\\private$\\TestQueue");
    if(hr != S_OK)
       return hr;

    VARIANT vtFalse;
    VariantInit(&vtFalse);
    vtFalse.vt = VT_BOOL;
    vtFalse.boolVal = FALSE;
    hr = ipQueueInfo->Create(&vtFalse, &vtFalse);
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: Document the hr value you get back.

Comment: There's also no check of `HRESULT` returned by `CoInitializeEx`

Answer (score 0):

MSDN says [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that because there is no way to control the order in which in-process servers are loaded or unloaded, CoInitializeEx should not be called from the [DllMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Are you calling `CreateQueue` from DllMain?